# what's meaning of "Remap to ancestor" in "git filter-branch"

Tags: git

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html

**Remap to ancestor**

By using rev-list(1) arguments, e.g., path limiters, you can limit the set of revisions which get rewritten. However, positive refs on the command line are distinguished: we don’t let them be excluded by such limiters. For this purpose, they are instead rewritten to point at the nearest ancestor that was not excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I think it says that when you are using the rev-list options, and one of those options would 'hide' one of your positive commit references (i.e. a reference to a commit you want to keep and filter) then rather than ignore it, the remapping will change your positive reference (so it won't keep the one you exactly specified) to one of it's ancestors that is still within the options (but it will at least keep an ancestor of the one you wanted ;-)

I guess that in some cases this means that the rev-list option can do the filtering (as in removal of unwanted commits) rather than have to programme the filter and select the `--prune-empty` option.